# Node.js modules installed through npm not recognized

Tags: node.js, npm

So I've installed and reinstalled node.js many times and tried various installs of the npm. I am currently on node version 0.6.11. When I try to install a new module with npm I get several errors. I am extremely new to programming with node but I have tried researching this problem but haven't found a proper answer. When I install a module with npm and then try to use it in command prompt nothing happens. All I get is for example

> > 'haraka' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> >     operable program or batch file.

This happens to every module I install. What am I missing here. Please help. I am getting really frustrated with node

Answer (score 0):

By default, npm will install packages locally, in `./node_modules`. So if you are in `/home/foo`:

```
user@host:/home/foo$ npm install Haraka
```

Haraka will be installed in `/home/foo/node_modules/Haraka`. If you want to install a module globally (by default in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`), supply the `-g` switch:

```
user@host:/home/foo$ sudo npm install -g Haraka
```

Haraka will be installed in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/Haraka`, and the command `haraka` will be symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/haraka`.

It's recommended that any dependencies be installed locally. This way, you never have to bother with different packages requiring different versions of their dependencies, aka "dependency hell". I have all my projects in `~/development/projects`, and each node project has it's own `node_modules` folder.